# How do I test if license service is installed on an Android device?

Tags: android

I have an application written in Java which I have just enabled for License Verification Library (LVL). During start up I invoke the LVL to "phone home" to Google Play to ensure that the app is licensed properly so the app can take action.

This code has been tested with various responses and on various devices and it works. Except for one device. On this device continuously fails with an error that it cannot bind to the service.

The offending line is part of LicenseChecker.java provided by Google in the LVL SDK:

```
boolean bindResult = mContext
      .bindService(
        new Intent(
        new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U="))),
    this, // ServiceConnection.
    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The Base64 string contains "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService" (I have no idea why it is encoded except perhaps as a weak form of obfuscation).

This device is just a cheap tablet I bought online for testing and then flashed with custom firmware. It's entirely possible that for whatever reason "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService" is not handled properly or not at all and I get this message.

It's also possible other devices owned by my customers might have this fault too I'd like to be able to convey a somewhat meaningful error message to them in this situation so they don't blame my app for a problem with their tablet.

I'm thinking I could either look for the process directory, or I could some how find out what services handle the named intent. Is that possible and if so how do I go about it? If I could tell the user as precisely as possible why the app is not going to run I can save myself a lot of grief.

Comment: Make sure Google Play is installed on that cheap tablet, otherwise LVL will not work.

Comment: Possible that the custom firmware is doing some DNS modification to disable license checking and ads?

Comment: Google Play is installed (and it updates itself too) but the license service is not working, or at least bindService is not working. If it could happen to me then I must assume it could happen to someone else. What I don't want happening is them blaming my app for their tablet's problem. If I just flat out reject them then they will blame me so I want some kind of information to direct them somewhere else and not blame me. There must be a way to figure out which service / activity / receiver is going to handle an intent if any and from that communicate the issue to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely for a cheap tablet, flashed with Custom firmware, that the version of Google Play you have is old or unofficial, and so the "Google Play Services" APK is missing or not up to date. Only a device with an official Google Play installation is guaranteed to work. I'd provide a message saying something like that.